# When i am using & why process isnt running in the background

Tags: c, linux, shell

i am trying to make my own shell in Linux using C language.
well, i succed to make "pormpt, basic commands and I/O redirection" but when i am trying to make "background execution of programs with &" i failed. its not working on background. for example the expected is :

```
> sleep 5 &
> cat file.txt
will print the content of file.txt
> [24617] retval: 0
```

but what is happening is :

```
> sleep 5 &
> [24617] retval: 0
> cat file.txt
will print the content of file.txt
```

this is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <termios.h>


#define MAX_WORD 10
#define MAX_CHAR 100
int input_redirection_flag;
int output_redirection_flag;
int background;
char* input_file=NULL;
char* output_file=NULL;
void remove_endOfLine(char line[]){
    int i=0;
    while(line[i]!='\n')
        i++;
    line[i]='\0';
}
void read_line(char line[]){
    char* ret=fgets(line,MAX_CHAR,stdin);
    remove_endOfLine(line);
    if(strcmp(line,"quit")==0 || ret==NULL)
        exit(0);
}
int process_line(char* temp[],char line[]){
    int i=0;
    temp[i]=strtok(line," ");
    while(temp[i]!=NULL){
            temp[++i]=strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    return 1;
}
int redirection_background_checking(char* temp[]){
    int i=0;
    background=0;
    while(temp[i] != NULL){
        if(strcmp(temp[i],">")==0){
            output_redirection_flag=1;
            output_file=temp[i+1];
            return i;
        }
        if(strcmp(temp[i],"<")==0){
            input_redirection_flag=1;
            input_file=temp[i+1];
            return i;
        }
        if(strcmp(temp[i],"&")==0){
            background=1;
            temp[i]=NULL;
        }
        i++;

    }
    return i;

}
void check_line(char* temp[]){
    int i=0;
    int output_redirection_cnt=0;
    int input_redirection_cnt=0;
    if(temp[i]==NULL){
        printf("NO COMMAND\n");
        return ;
    }
    while(temp[i] !=NULL){
        if(strcmp(temp[i],">")==0)
            output_redirection_cnt++;
        if(strcmp(temp[i],"<")==0)
            input_redirection_cnt++;

        i++;
    }
    if(output_redirection_cnt+input_redirection_cnt>1){
        printf("you cannot use more than 1 signal.");
        temp[0]=NULL;
    }
}
int read_parse_line(char* args[],char line[]){
    char* temp[MAX_WORD];
    int pos;
    int i=0;
    read_line(line);
    process_line(temp,line);
    check_line(temp);
    pos=redirection_background_checking(temp);
    while(i<pos){
        args[i]=temp[i];
        i++;
    }
    args[i]=NULL;
    i++;

}
int main()
{
    char line[MAX_CHAR];
    char* args[MAX_WORD];
    char * tokens[MAX_WORD];
    printf("> ");
    fflush(stdout);
    while(read_parse_line(args,line)){
        pid_t pid=fork();
        if(pid==0){
            if(input_redirection_flag==1&&input_file!=NULL)
                dup2(open(input_file,O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0777),0);
            if(output_redirection_flag==1&&output_file!=NULL)
                dup2(open(output_file,O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0777),1);
            execvp(args[0],args);
        }
        else if(pid<0){
            printf("failed Process");
        }
        else{
            input_redirection_flag=0;
            output_redirection_flag=0;
            input_file=NULL;
            output_file=NULL;
        }
        if (background == 0){
           waitpid(pid,NULL,0);

        }else{

         printf("[%d] retval: %d\n",pid,0);
        }
        if(background == 1 && args[1]=="quit")
            break;

        printf("> ");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have that expectation, your code shouldn't have

        `if (background == 0){
           waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
        }else{
         printf("[%d] retval: %d\n",pid,0);
        }` IOW, your code _IS_ running in the background, but you're printing a message immediately after spawning the process, which seems to be confusing you.

Comment: even after i removed it the output thet i had is :
> sleep 5 &
> [24617] retval: 0
> cat file.txt
after 5 second will print the content of file.txt

Comment: exactly i want the message to be printed after the background process be finish. and until it will be finish i will be able to write another command

Comment: `echo "sleep 2; echo slept" > my_script; chmod +x my_script`. Then from your shell: `./my_script & echo whatever` and the whatever will come before `slept`.

Comment: You're going to need to store the backgrounded pids and check if they finished (with `if(0==waitpid(pid,&status,WNOHANG)){ /*...*/` before you write each next prompt (at least that's what shells do).

Comment: i think this is the solution , i will try it thank you